# iOS7 view behind statusbar within UINavigationController with Navigationbar hidden

Tags: ios

I have a ViewController in a UINavigationController. The NavigationBar is hidden.

I don't want the statusbar to overlay the view.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

This didn't do the trick with navigationbar hidden.

Can anyone provide me information about how to do this?

My app needs to support iOS6 and iOS7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workarround is to set the y position to +=62 and use the ios 6/7 deltas with -62